# Powerpoint/ExecuteMSO Command in C# not immediately executing. The lines of code following the command are causing mess because of this

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, comaddin

following is the code I am using to cut - paste an existing  column in a powerpoint table into a newly added column. After pasting I am doing out some operations like merging cells in the column pasted. The only thing I found out is the column was still not pasted after running the executemso command, but as soon as the function execution got over, I was able to see the column correctly paste over UI, but the operation of merging the cells was overridden with the paste, which suggests the actual paste happened so late
...

```
        Shape.Table.Columns.Add(1);
        Shape.Table.Columns[1].Width = Shape.Table.Columns[3].Width;
        Shape.Table.Columns[3].Select();
        Toolbox.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Cut();
        Shape.Table.Columns[1].Select();            
       
       
      Toolbox.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting");
        PowerPoint.Cell celltoMerge = Shape.Table.Columns[1].Cells[2]; // at this point columns are not actually pasted 
        celltoMerge.Merge(Shape.Table.Columns[1].Cells[3]);
```

...

Comment: A frequently asked question here. I/O operations (copy, paste, open, save, etc.) operate more slowly that your code does. Here's a page with several workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158278/wait-some-seconds-without-blocking-ui-execution