# Can I make delay code that works in NET. 3.5?

Tags: c#, delay

I have a code and I need a delay but I'm working in NET. 3.5 and I can't use Thread.Sleep because the whole program doesn't respond. Are there any alternatives? I'm using C# and WinForms. Thats my code where I want to add the delay:

```
private async void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10000;
    serialPort.WriteTimeout = 10000;
    serialPort.Open();
    serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
    serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
    label1.Visible = true;
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    label1.Visible = false;
    label2.Visible = true;
    serialPort.WriteLine("ATD");
    serialPort.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    serialPort.ReadLine();
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    serialPort.Close();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    serialPort.Open();
    serialPort.WriteLine("ATA");
    serialPort.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    serialPort.ReadLine();
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
    serialPort.Close();
}
```

Comment: Going to need more than that. WHAT kind of app are you making here?...

Comment: I wrote it now in the post :) Sorry about that

Comment: First-off, what exactly do you mean by ".NET 3.x"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855885/11683?

Comment: NET Framework 3.5

Comment: If you mean .NET Framework 3.X, then the correct solution would be to [use a BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation).

Comment: Where-and-how are you even running .NET Framework 3.5? Every supported platform for .NET Fx 3.5 supports .NET Fx 4.8, so why not just update the application instead?

Comment: @Yarik How can `BackgroundWorker` be used as a non-blocking millisecond-precision alternative to `Task.Delay`?

Comment: If WinForms, you could drop a Timer control on your form and use the Tick() event.

Comment: @Dai, you put your whole method with delays into the `DoWork` event handler, and use `ReportProgress` to update the UI such as your labels.

Comment: I noticed that the method is `Form6_Load` - which means you've got at least 5 other `Form` classes in your project that are still using their unhelpfully undescriptive default names `Form1` through `Form6` - why is it that so many people simply never give their objects and types _good names_? _le sigh...)

Comment: @Yarik That's not non-blocking though...

Comment: @Dai, I'm not sure what do you mean by "not non-blocking" since `DoWork` runs on background thread.

Comment: if you want to move your code to background worker [such as threadpool] - you need to handle on the main thread [beginInvoke] all UI work.

Answer (score 1):

If we go back to the .NET Framework 3.5 ways to do things, then the most widely used solution would be to [use a `BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation), which is just a handy wrapper around `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

What you do is you drop `BackgroundWorker` onto your form, subscribe to the `DoWork` event, and move your serial port logic there. If you need to access any UI controls, you either use `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`, or, even better, `Control.Invoke` as shown below.

```
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10000;
    serialPort.WriteTimeout = 10000;
    serialPort.Open();
    serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
    serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
    Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Visible = true));
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Visible = false));
    Invoke(new Action(() => label2.Visible = true));
    serialPort.WriteLine("ATD");
    serialPort.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    serialPort.ReadLine();
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    serialPort.Close();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    serialPort.Open();
    serialPort.WriteLine("ATA");
    serialPort.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    serialPort.ReadLine();
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
    serialPort.Close();
}
```

**But of course, I would highly recommend to update your project to .NET Framework 4.5 (at least), and use `async/await` with `Task.Delay`.**

Answer (score -1):

Since you mention you work with .Net 3.5 you cannot use Tasks. Use Threadpool instead.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(doJob, null);
private static void doJob(object obj)
{
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
     //do your job here
}
```

Comment: If you're using the threadpool then **don't** block those threads either by using `Thread.Sleep` - instead you should yield the thread back to the pool (like what `await` does, but without the benefit of the `await` keyword) and request a continuation using a `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer` (depending on your requirements)

Comment: I like your comment. But it looks as if ht need the most simple solution...he just wants to open a serial port...

Comment: They're doing more than just opening a serial-port, they're attempting some kind of interactive and almost-real-time user-interface for it - whatever the OP's doing I'm getting the impression it's nontrivial.

Comment: I'm attempting to dial my Dial-Up modem and on my UI it should show something like label1 when the ATD Command is executed :)