# How can i display in a middle of a progressBar some text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

What i want to do is to show in the middle of the progressBar a text in red and that the text will blink until the progressBar operation end getting to 100%.

The text to display is: Processing Please Wait
In the end in the background completed event just to stop the blinking and display instead: Processing Please Wait to display: Operation Ended or something like that maybe: Process Ended or Finished.

I forgot to mention that my progressBar1 i'm using is a costum UserControl i did and not the regular progressBar for example after dragging this to my form1 designer this progressBar dosen't have the Increment property.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace VistaStyleProgressBar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A replacement for the default ProgressBar control.
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultEvent("ValueChanged")]
    public class ProgressBar : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    {

        #region -  Designer  -

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the control and initialize it.
        /// </summary>
        public ProgressBar()
        {
            // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            if (!InDesignMode())
            {
                mGlowAnimation.Tick += new EventHandler(mGlowAnimation_Tick);
                mGlowAnimation.Interval = 15;
                if (Value < MaxValue) { mGlowAnimation.Start(); }
            }
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region -  Component Designer  -

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // 
            // ProgressBar
            // 
            this.Name = "ProgressBar";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(264, 32);
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(ProgressBar_Paint);
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region -  Properties  -

        private int mGlowPosition = -325;
        private Timer mGlowAnimation = new Timer();

        #region -  Value  -

        private int mValue = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// The value that is displayed on the progress bar.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Value"),
        DefaultValue(0),
        Description("The value that is displayed on the progress bar.")]
        public int Value
        {
            get { return mValue; }
            set
            {
                if (value > MaxValue || value < MinValue) { return; }
                mValue = value;
                if (value < MaxValue) { mGlowAnimation.Start(); }
                if (value == MaxValue) { mGlowAnimation.Stop(); }
                ValueChangedHandler vc = ValueChanged;
                if (vc != null) { vc(this, new System.EventArgs()); }
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private int mMaxValue = 100;
        /// <summary>
        /// The maximum value for the Value property.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Value"),
        DefaultValue(100),
        Description("The maximum value for the Value property.")]
        public int MaxValue
        {
            get { return mMaxValue; }
            set
            {
                mMaxValue = value;
                if (value > MaxValue) { Value = MaxValue; }
                if (Value < MaxValue) { mGlowAnimation.Start(); }
                MaxChangedHandler mc = MaxChanged;
                if (mc != null) { mc(this, new System.EventArgs()); }
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private int mMinValue = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// The minimum value for the Value property.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Value"),
        DefaultValue(0),
        Description("The minimum value for the Value property.")]
        public int MinValue
        {
            get { return mMinValue; }
            set
            {
                mMinValue = value;
                if (value < MinValue) { Value = MinValue; }
                MinChangedHandler mc = MinChanged;
                if (mc != null) { mc(this, new System.EventArgs()); }
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region -  Bar  -

        private Color mStartColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 211, 40);
        /// <summary>
        /// The start color for the progress bar.
        /// 210, 000, 000 = Red
        /// 210, 202, 000 = Yellow
        /// 000, 163, 211 = Blue
        /// 000, 211, 040 = Green
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Bar"),
        DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "210, 0, 0"),
        Description("The start color for the progress bar." +
                    "210, 000, 000 = Red\n" +
                    "210, 202, 000 = Yellow\n" +
                    "000, 163, 211 = Blue\n" +
                    "000, 211, 040 = Green\n")]
        public Color StartColor
        {
            get { return mStartColor; }
            set { mStartColor = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        private Color mEndColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 211, 40);
        /// <summary>
        /// The end color for the progress bar.
        /// 210, 000, 000 = Red
        /// 210, 202, 000 = Yellow
        /// 000, 163, 211 = Blue
        /// 000, 211, 040 = Green
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Bar"),
        DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 211, 40"),
        Description("The end color for the progress bar." +
            "210, 000, 000 = Red\n" +
            "210, 202, 000 = Yellow\n" +
            "000, 163, 211 = Blue\n" +
            "000, 211, 040 = Green\n")]
        public Color EndColor
        {
            get { return mEndColor; }
            set { mEndColor = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region -  Highlights and Glows  -

        private Color mHighlightColor = Color.White;
        /// <summary>
        /// The color of the highlights.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Highlights and Glows"),
        DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "White"),
        Description("The color of the highlights.")]
        public Color HighlightColor
        {
            get { return mHighlightColor; }
            set { mHighlightColor = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        private Color mBackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(201, 201, 201);
        /// <summary>
        /// The color of the background.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Highlights and Glows"),
        DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "201,201,201"),
        Description("The color of the background.")]
        public Color BackgroundColor
        {
            get { return mBackgroundColor; }
            set { mBackgroundColor = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        private bool mAnimate = true;
        /// <summary>
        /// Whether the glow is animated.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Highlights and Glows"),
        DefaultValue(typeof(bool), "true"),
        Description("Whether the glow is animated or not.")]
        public bool Animate
        {
            get { return mAnimate; }
            set
            {
                mAnimate = value;
                if (value) { mGlowAnimation.Start(); } else { mGlowAnimation.Stop(); }
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private Color mGlowColor = Color.FromArgb(150, 255, 255, 255);
        /// <summary>
        /// The color of the glow.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Highlights and Glows"),
        DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "150, 255, 255, 255"),
        Description("The color of the glow.")]
        public Color GlowColor
        {
            get { return mGlowColor; }
            set { mGlowColor = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }

        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region -  Drawing  -

        private void DrawBackground(Graphics g)
        {
            Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle; r.Width--; r.Height--;
            GraphicsPath rr = RoundRect(r, 2, 2, 2, 2);
            g.FillPath(new SolidBrush(this.BackgroundColor), rr);
        }

        private void DrawBackgroundShadows(Graphics g)
        {
            Rectangle lr = new Rectangle(2, 2, 10, this.Height - 5);
            LinearGradientBrush lg = new LinearGradientBrush(lr, Color.FromArgb(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                                             Color.Transparent,
                                                             LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
            lr.X--;
            g.FillRectangle(lg, lr);

            Rectangle rr = new Rectangle(this.Width - 12, 2, 10, this.Height - 5);
            LinearGradientBrush rg = new LinearGradientBrush(rr, Color.Transparent,
                                                             Color.FromArgb(20, 0, 0, 0),
                                                             LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
            g.FillRectangle(rg, rr);
        }

        private void DrawBar(Graphics g)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(1, 2, this.Width - 3, this.Height - 3);
            r.Width = (int)(Value * 1.0F / (MaxValue - MinValue) * this.Width);
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(GetIntermediateColor()), r);
        }

        private void DrawBarShadows(Graphics g)
        {
            Rectangle lr = new Rectangle(1, 2, 15, this.Height - 3);
            LinearGradientBrush lg = new LinearGradientBrush(lr, Color.White, Color.White,
                                                             LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);

            ColorBlend lc = new ColorBlend(3);
            lc.Colors = new Color[] { Color.Transparent, Color.FromArgb(40, 0, 0, 0), Color.Transparent };
            lc.Positions = new float[] { 0.0F, 0.2F, 1.0F };
            lg.InterpolationColors = lc;

            lr.X--;
            g.FillRectangle(lg, lr);

            Rectangle rr = new Rectangle(this.Width - 3, 2, 15, this.Height - 3);
            rr.X = (int)(Value * 1.0F / (MaxValue - MinValue) * this.Width) - 14;
            LinearGradientBrush rg = new LinearGradientBrush(rr, Color.Black, Color.Black,
                                                             LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);

            ColorBlend rc = new ColorBlend(3);
            rc.Colors = new Color[] { Color.Transparent, Color.FromArgb(40, 0, 0, 0), Color.Transparent };
            rc.Positions = new float[] { 0.0F, 0.8F, 1.0F };
            rg.InterpolationColors = rc;

            g.FillRectangle(rg, rr);
        }

        private void DrawHighlight(Graphics g)
        {
            Rectangle tr = new Rectangle(1, 1, this.Width - 1, 6);
            GraphicsPath tp = RoundRect(tr, 2, 2, 0, 0);

            g.SetClip(tp);
            LinearGradientBrush tg = new LinearGradientBrush(tr, Color.White,
                                                             Color.FromArgb(128, Color.White),
                                                             LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
            g.FillPath(tg, tp);
            g.ResetClip();

            Rectangle br = new Rectangle(1, this.Height - 8, this.Width - 1, 6);
            GraphicsPath bp = RoundRect(br, 0, 0, 2, 2);

            g.SetClip(bp);
            LinearGradientBrush bg = new LinearGradientBrush(br, Color.Transparent,
                                                             Color.FromArgb(100, this.HighlightColor),
                                                             LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
            g.FillPath(bg, bp);
            g.ResetClip();
        }

        private void DrawInnerStroke(Graphics g)
        {
            Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;
            r.X++; r.Y++; r.Width -= 3; r.Height -= 3;
            GraphicsPath rr = RoundRect(r, 2, 2, 2, 2);
            g.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.White)), rr);
        }

        private void DrawGlow(Graphics g)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(mGlowPosition, 0, 60, this.Height);
            LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(r, Color.White, Color.White,
                                                              LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);

            ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend(4);
            cb.Colors = new Color[] { Color.Transparent, this.GlowColor, this.GlowColor, Color.Transparent };
            cb.Positions = new float[] { 0.0F, 0.5F, 0.6F, 1.0F };
            lgb.InterpolationColors = cb;

            Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(1, 2, this.Width - 3, this.Height - 3);
            clip.Width = (int)(Value * 1.0F / (MaxValue - MinValue) * this.Width);
            g.SetClip(clip);
            g.FillRectangle(lgb, r);
            g.ResetClip();
        }

        private void DrawOuterStroke(Graphics g)
        {
            Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle; r.Width--; r.Height--;
            GraphicsPath rr = RoundRect(r, 2, 2, 2, 2);
            g.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(178, 178, 178)), rr);
        }

        #endregion

        #region -  Functions  -

        private GraphicsPath RoundRect(RectangleF r, float r1, float r2, float r3, float r4)
        {
            float x = r.X, y = r.Y, w = r.Width, h = r.Height;
            GraphicsPath rr = new GraphicsPath();
            rr.AddBezier(x, y + r1, x, y, x + r1, y, x + r1, y);
            rr.AddLine(x + r1, y, x + w - r2, y);
            rr.AddBezier(x + w - r2, y, x + w, y, x + w, y + r2, x + w, y + r2);
            rr.AddLine(x + w, y + r2, x + w, y + h - r3);
            rr.AddBezier(x + w, y + h - r3, x + w, y + h, x + w - r3, y + h, x + w - r3, y + h);
            rr.AddLine(x + w - r3, y + h, x + r4, y + h);
            rr.AddBezier(x + r4, y + h, x, y + h, x, y + h - r4, x, y + h - r4);
            rr.AddLine(x, y + h - r4, x, y + r1);
            return rr;
        }

        private bool InDesignMode()
        {
            return (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime);
        }

        private Color GetIntermediateColor()
        {
            Color c = this.StartColor;
            Color c2 = this.EndColor;

            float pc = this.Value * 1.0F / (this.MaxValue - this.MinValue);

            int ca = c.A, cr = c.R, cg = c.G, cb = c.B;
            int c2a = c2.A, c2r = c2.R, c2g = c2.G, c2b = c2.B;

            int a = (int)Math.Abs(ca + (ca - c2a) * pc);
            int r = (int)Math.Abs(cr - ((cr - c2r) * pc));
            int g = (int)Math.Abs(cg - ((cg - c2g) * pc));
            int b = (int)Math.Abs(cb - ((cb - c2b) * pc));

            if (a > 255) { a = 255; }
            if (r > 255) { r = 255; }
            if (g > 255) { g = 255; }
            if (b > 255) { b = 255; }

            return (Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));
        }

        #endregion

        #region -  Other  -

        private void ProgressBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            DrawBackground(e.Graphics);
            DrawBackgroundShadows(e.Graphics);
            DrawBar(e.Graphics);
            DrawBarShadows(e.Graphics);
            DrawHighlight(e.Graphics);
            DrawInnerStroke(e.Graphics);
            DrawGlow(e.Graphics);
            DrawOuterStroke(e.Graphics);
        }

        private void mGlowAnimation_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Animate)
            {
                mGlowPosition += 4;
                if (mGlowPosition > this.Width)
                {
                    mGlowPosition = -300;
                }
                this.Invalidate();
            }
            else
            {
                mGlowAnimation.Stop();
                mGlowPosition = -320;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region -  Events  -

        /// <summary>
        /// When the Value property is changed.
        /// </summary>
        public delegate void ValueChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        /// <summary>
        /// When the Value property is changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event ValueChangedHandler ValueChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// When the MinValue property is changed.
        /// </summary>
        public delegate void MinChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        /// <summary>
        /// When the MinValue property is changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event MinChangedHandler MinChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// When the MaxValue property is changed.
        /// </summary>
        public delegate void MaxChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
        /// <summary>
        /// When the MaxValue property is changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event MaxChangedHandler MaxChanged;

        #endregion

    }
}
```

I tried this case the Increment property not exist so it's a problem.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Increment(+1);
    int percent = progressBar1.Value;
    progressBar1
        .CreateGraphics()
        .DrawString(
            percent.ToString() + "%", 
            new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), 
            Brushes.Black, 
            new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, 
            progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7)
        );
    if (progressBar1.Value >= 99)
    {
        timer2.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is make a label with the desired text and then add to the background worker:

```
if ( progressBar1.Value == 100% )
{
   label1.Text = "Process finished";
}
```

If you cant see the label and it is hidden behind the processBar change the location of the label to front

Hope I could help!

Edit: This link should explain the blinking event [How to implement a blinking label on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042516/how-to-implement-a-blinking-label-on-a-form)

Answer (score 1):

Have wrote **no blinking/flickering** TextProgressBar

You can find source code here: https://github.com/ukushu/TextProgressBar

Sample:

[image: no blinking/flickering TextProgressBar]